# ASP.NET Core + Angular deploy Artifact with Azure DevOps release pipeline

Tags: angular, asp.net-core, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

I created a asp.net core project with Angular. So it's 1 monolotic application instead of two applications.

My problem is as follows:

[image]

Which package/folder should I select to deploy? the Dist folder or the zip file? Or the folder named "artifactnametest"?

Comment: How about the issue? Does the answer below resolved your question, If not, would you please let me know the latest information about this issue?

Comment: It didnt fix it because there is another problem. But I made a different issue for that. I will close this one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should publish your asp net core app instead.

Here's a sample build filefrom one of our projects. This is for asp.net core only. For angular apps we do some extra stuff like run `npm install` in a different task, but the principle is the same.

```yaml
# ASP.NET Core (.NET Framework)
# Build and test ASP.NET Core projects targeting the full .NET Framework.
# Add steps that publish symbols, save build artifacts, and more:
# https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/devops/pipelines/languages/dotnet-core

trigger:
- master

pool:
  vmImage: 'windows-latest'

variables:
  solution: '**/*.sln'
  buildPlatform: 'Any CPU'
  buildConfiguration: 'Release'
  runtime: 'win-x64'

steps:
- task: NuGetToolInstaller@1

# Restore all nuget packages and .net core tools
- task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
  inputs:
    command: 'custom'
    projects: '**/*.csproj'
    custom: 'restore'
    arguments: '-r $(runtime)'

# Build projects
- task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
  inputs:
    command: 'build'
    projects: '**/*.csproj'
    arguments: '-c $(BuildConfiguration) --no-restore -r $(runtime)'

# Publish all projects to /staging/ci-build/<ProjectName>/
- task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
  inputs:
    command: 'publish'
    publishWebProjects: false
    projects: |
      **/*Client.csproj
      **/*WorkerService.csproj
      **/*Server.csproj
    arguments: '-c $(BuildConfiguration) -o $(Build.StagingDirectory)/ci-build --no-build --self-contained -r $(runtime)'
    zipAfterPublish: false

# Archive the /staging/ci-build folder to /staging/RemoteData.<BuildNumber>
- task: ArchiveFiles@2
  inputs:
    rootFolderOrFile: '$(Build.StagingDirectory)/ci-build'
    includeRootFolder: false
    archiveType: 'zip'
    archiveFile: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/RemoteData.$(Build.BuildNumber).zip'
    replaceExistingArchive: true

# Publish the zipfile as artifact
- task: PublishBuildArtifacts@1
  inputs:
    PathtoPublish: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/RemoteData.$(Build.BuildNumber).zip'
    ArtifactName: 'RemoteData.$(Build.BuildNumber)'
    publishLocation: 'Container'
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. But what happens with the dist folder?

Comment: hmm have you tried locally publishing your app? you can see what the output looks like

Comment: "This is for asp.net core only. For angular apps we do some extra stuff like run npm install in a different task". But this is a monolotic application. The asp.net core app does things like ng build -- prod etc... so why write more code for that in te yaml file?

Comment: @MYil only to put them in individual build tasks. That helps with finding out what tasks take a long time. For example npm update took a long time so we applied caching at some point; https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/release/caching?view=azure-devops#nodejsnpm 
Other than that publishing will indeed take care of everything.

Comment: Can I ask you one more question? Why publish multiple of those projects? In my buildpipeline I publish like this: - task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
  inputs:
    command: 'publish'
    publishWebProjects: true
    arguments: '--configuration $(BuildConfiguration) --output $(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)'
    zipAfterPublish: true

Comment: @MYil sure you can! this is a sample i took from a project, we have the server, a workerservice (for hangfire.io) and a client for that server. So there's 3 apps (remember this does not use angular per say, but i adapted this .yml file to my angular app project - but i cannot post that).  Those client and service apps are not asp.net core - just normal .net core apps. You can just publish all webapps like you are already doing.

Comment: I just placed the dist folder and the dotnet publish folder in a zip file and deployed to a linux asp.net core 3.1 azure app service but it doesn't work.. How can the app center know what to do with the zip and both folders?

Answer (score 1):

> Which package/folder should I select to deploy? the Dist folder or the zip file? Or the folder named "artifactnametest"?

I agree with prasun. We could copy the NPM dist folder from working directory to staging directory, then zip the entire staging directory and publish it.

Alternatively, we could add two artifacts in the release pipeline to deploy Dist folder and zip file:

[image]

[image]

You could check this document [Create a build pipeline for Angular and ASP.NET Core apps with Visual Studio Team Services](https://offering.solutions/blog/articles/2018/03/08/create-a-build-pipeline-for-angular-and-asp.net-core-apps-with-visual-studio-team-services/) for some details.

Answer (score 0):

I have done this implementation using Dotnet Build and NPM build.
First do an NPM build and generate a dist folder. Then do a asp.net build. Once build is done copy the files to Build.artifactstagingdirectory.
Similarly for NPM dist copy the folder from working directory to staging directory inside folder where you want to keep the same.
Then you can zip the entire staging directory and publish the same. Below is the sample code snippet. Instead of MsBuild you can replace it with DotNetCore@2 task

```yaml
    trigger:
        branches:
          include:
          - master
      
    pool:
      name: Azure Pipelines
      vmImage: 'windows-2019'
      demands:
        - npm
        - msbuild
        - visualstudio
    
    variables: 
      configuration: release
      BuildConfiguration: "Release"
      platform: x64
    
    stages:
    - stage: Build
      jobs:
      - job: Build
        steps:
        - task: NuGetToolInstaller@0
          displayName: 'Use NuGet 4.4.1'
          inputs:
            versionSpec: 4.4.1
        - task: NuGetCommand@2
          displayName: 'NuGet restore'
          inputs:
            restoreSolution: '$(Parameters.solution)'
            vstsFeed: '34356gsgv643a'
        - task: Npm@1
          displayName: 'npm install'
          inputs:
            workingDir: angularfoldername
            verbose: false
        - task: Npm@1
          displayName: 'npm custom'
          inputs:
            command: custom
            workingDir: angularfoldername
            verbose: false
            customCommand: 'run build'
        - task: MSBuild@1
          displayName: 'Build solution dotnet.csproj'
          inputs:
            solution: dotnet.csproj
            msbuildArguments: '/t:build /p:outputpath="$(build.artifactstagingdirectory)" /property:langversion=latest'
        - task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
          displayName: Test
          inputs:
            command: test
            projects: '$(Parameters.TestProjects)'
            arguments: '--configuration $(BuildConfiguration)'
        - task: CopyFiles@2
          displayName: 'Copy Files to: $(build.artifactstagingdirectory)\_PublishedWebsites\dotnet\angularfolder'
          inputs:
            SourceFolder: 'angularfoldername'
            Contents: '**'
            TargetFolder: '$(build.artifactstagingdirectory)\_PublishedWebsites\dotnet\angularfoldername'
           - task: PublishBuildArtifacts@1
          displayName: 'Publish Artifact: drop'
          inputs:
            PathtoPublish: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)\_PublishedWebsites'
```

Comment: What happens when I zip the dist folder and the asp.net core folder? I deploy it, and then? How will Azure Web Service know what to do with both of them?

Comment: if I understood correctly, you are trying to zip both folders independently. Yes, this is possible however in this case deployment will happen separately.

example: You deploying backend(Dotnetcore). Now during frontend deployment, you will define the virtual directory path and azure DevOps will deploy the folder(dist). It will unzip itself during deployment

However, if we Deploy it together then there is no need to zip dist separately