# The serve command requires to be run in an Angular project - Azure App Service (.NetCore and Angular app)

Tags: angular, azure, asp.net-core, azure-web-app-service

I have an Angular and.NetCore app that I am deploying to Azure App Service (Windows).

I use Azure Pipelines, here is my pipeline configuration
[Pipeline Config](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3x2Lo.png)

When I deploy to app service this is my folder structure.
[Whole App Service](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hmnc4.png)

This is inside my **ClientApp** folder.
[ClientApp Folder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/APlRP.png)

I get this error, I have been trying for 2 weeks now.

```
The serve command requires to be run in an Angular project, but a project definition could not be found. fail: Microsoft.AspNetCore.SpaServices[0]
      The serve command requires to be run in an Angular project, but a project definition could not be found.
```

Please help me and tell me where I have missed my configuration.
Thank You, everyone

Comment: If anyone did this successfully please share your folder structure from the kudo console of the ClientApp and main. Thank you

Comment: What is the language and version of the webapps you have choosen ?

Comment: You can read this post, maybe it will help you. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62949194/asp-net-core-angular-deploy-artifact-with-azure-devops-release-pipeline

Comment: are you using `ng serve` to start the server? since the clientApp folder is a Dist build created you would need a server (IIS,Nginx) to host those static files.

Comment: @NikhilWalvekar yes I am

Comment: Has Any of you done this(deploying angular and asp.net core) Please share

Comment: Asp.netcore 5, angular 11, node 14

Comment: @NikhilWalvekar the thing is I have done this and the command executes perfectly but they tell that no angular project found

Comment: Here is blog from @pankaj-parkar https://medium.com/ngconf/angular-on-azure-part-i-d842e8f76462

Comment: Try this: `ng update @angular/cli --from=1.7.4 --migrate-only` Modify the version with your angular cli.

Comment: Doesnt Work @DorisLv

Comment: @NikhilWalvekar thats NodeJs and Angular. I need Asp.netcore and angular

Comment: Are you using IIS to deploy the .netCore app? do you plan to run both Angular & .netCore app on the same app service?

Comment: @NikhilWalvekar yes

Comment: Thank You everyone who assisted me here

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, I finally found the solution. You cannot run `ng serve` because obviously, it should be static file rendered. The problem was the env variable not set to "Production". Then you need to have the folder structure like "ClientApp/Dist".

The second issue was not using `--prod`.

Hope this saves someones time.